# Truncating the image in the frequency domain

Tags: image-processing

From the first sentence of section 4 in the paper "[A harmonic analysis view on neuroscience imaging](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Edlabate/orion_fft2011.pdf)",

> Since all images have compact support in the space domain $\mathbb{R}^d$ ($d = 2$ or $d = 3$), their
> conversion from analogue to digital form occurring during acquisition requires truncating the image in the frequency domain.

I can't understand why it requires truncating the image in the 'frequency domain'.

Is this because the condition, all images are compactly supported? If then, why?
Generally, the Fourier transform of compactly supported function (or signal) does not have compactly supported in frequency variable.

There is another question. Why is $L^2$-norm considered to define essential bandwidth not general $L^p$-norm?